# Etymology of the suffix -ino

Tags: etymology, suffix, homograph

I don't speak Italian, but if I'm not mistaken, -ino is both a diminutive (e.g. ragazzo ‘boy’ – ragazzino ‘little boy’) and a suffix that creates nationality names (e. g. tunisino means 'Tunisian'). Is there a way to check if there is an etymological link between these two meanings of the suffix? Like, if they share an origin, or if there is a connection between them semantically? Mainly what interests me is if they are the **same** morpheme with 2 meanings (i.e. a case of polysemy) or two different morphemes that **just happen** to have the same form (i.e. a case of homonymy). It would really give me a peace of mind if I knew the answer :) If, by any chance you could provide any sources/dictionaries/anything that would help me with this question (otherwise even a simple answer will do, in case you happen to know the answer), I'd be eternally grateful. My browsings on google haven't helped at all.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this study](https://doi.org/10.4000/lexis.403), they both come from Latin *-īnus*:

> Data from Romance languages (§ 4.1), from Greek (§ 4.2), and from
> Slavonic languages (§ 4.3) give evidence in favor of this second hypothesis: the shift in meaning of It. *-ino* (in *tavolino* "small table"), Gr. *-άκι* (in *λαθάκι* "a pardonable error"), Blg. *-ec/-íca* (in *brátec* "little brother" / *zeníca* "little woman"), etc. towards the current diminutive value took its first steps in the designation of the genealogical relation between father and son and between the adult and the young.

> Some of the most widely used Romance diminutive suffixes, It. *-ino*, sp. *–ín*, port. *‑inho*, are the outcome of a single Latin suffix, -īnus, the various semantic readings of which are usually traced back to a vague relational value (*cănīnus* "pertaining to the dog"; *vespertīnus* "happening in the evening", *Sābātīnus* "of Sabate, a town in Etruria", etc.)

This semantic development has happened in Slavic languages as well, with an apparently unrelated suffix [-it'ь](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/-i%C5%A5%D1%8C). Its reflexes form patronyms (Russian *Иванович* [Ivanovich] "son of Ivan"), demonyms (Russian *москвич* [moskvich] "resident of Moscow"), diminutives (Serbo-Croatian *Божић* [Bozhich] "Yuletide", literally "small god") and agent nouns (Macedonian *водич* [vodich] "guide").